# Custom Fonts in Java - getResourceAsStream not working in IntelliJ IDEA but DOES work in JAR

Tags: java, fonts, intellij-idea, inputstream, getresource

I'm trying to package my Java application so that other people can run it. I have no experience with this as I've always dealt with the applications through the IDE. I'm using a custom font and I use the code

```
 vectorFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("Vectorb.ttf"));
```

which does not work because in the JAR, the "filesystem" does not exist, or so I've been told. So I was suggested to replace `new File()` with `getClass().getResourceAsStream("Vectorb.ttf")` which works totally fine after I publish and run the JAR, but if I try to build and run the same code in IntelliJ, it throws an exception `"Problem reading font data."` I have also tried adding `getClass().getClassLoader()` to no avail.

Please, what is the issue here, and how do I fix it? This is IntelliJ Community edition.

Comment: Where do you have the Vectorb.ttf file stored? This is usually a problem with the file not being in the resources directory.

Comment: Do I need to have a specific directory entitled "resources"

Comment: @EngineerDollery Your suggestion worked. I put everything in a resources folder and tagged it as such and smooth sailing. Thanks again!